# Determine value of parameters in a matrix such that it is unitary

Tags: equation-solving, matrix

My goal is, given some vectors, multiply them by some constants and stack them as the columns of a matrix $U$. Then I want to know what are the values of the constants such that the resulting matrix $U$ is unitary, so, assuming real components:

$U^{t}=U^{-1}$
where the 't' indicates transpose.

More specifically I have the 3 vectors {1, -1, 1}, {-1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0}. I then multiply them by 3 different constants $x_{1}, x_{2},x_{3}$ and construct the U matrix using the obtained vectors as columns:

$\begin{equation}U=\begin{pmatrix}x_{1}&-x_{2}&x_{3}\\-x_{1} &0&x_{3}\\x_{1}&x_{2}&0 \end{pmatrix} \end{equation}$.

I now want to determine $x_{1}, x_{2},x_{3}$ such that $U^{t}=U^{-1}$. I have tried on Mathematica with:

```
Solve[{Inverse[U] == Transpose[U]}, {x1,x2, x3}]
```

but it doesn't work. How should I do it?

Comment: It appears that there is not a solution to this

Comment: "but it doesn't work" - it actually works fine: it returns `{ }`, which indicates that there are no solutions to your equations.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it arises only due to a confusion of the Mathematica output or the statement of the mathematical problem. Mathematica gives the correct result indicating that there's no solution to the question asked.

Answer (score 3):

Expanding my comment:

```
U = {{x1, -x2, x3}, {-x1, 0, x3}, {x1, x2, 0}};
U // MatrixForm
```

> [image: mat1]

The other required matrices

```
Inverse[U] // MatrixForm
Transpose[U] // MatrixForm
```

> [image: mat2]

> [image: mat3]

I am hoping that now it is clear, but in case it is not consider the `x1` solution

```
sltn = Solve[1/(3 x1) == x1]
```

which can be solved easily

> [image: sltn]

For the `x2` and similarly `x3` you have

```
sltn = Solve[{1/(3 xi) == xi, 1/(3 xi) == 0}, xi]
```

which cannot be solved. Finally, another way to see that this has no solutions

```
ComplexExpand[
  ConjugateTranspose[U].U - IdentityMatrix[3]] // MatrixForm
```

> [image: finalmat]